# Need to countplot the data types in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a seaborn count plot for the different data types in a data frame.  For instance in the example below, I should get a bar for float64 with a count of 3 and int64 with the count of 1.
I found someone did it by passing df.dtypes as an x or y parameter but I keep getting an error. 
TypeError: data type "" not understood
Please does anyone know how to do this?   Thanks for your help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[12, 4, 5, None, 1],  
                   "B":[7, 2, 54, 3, None],  
                   "C":[20, 16, 11, 3, 8],  
                   "D":[14, 3, None, 2, 6]})  

print(df.dtypes)
sns.countplot(y=df.dtypes, data=df)
plt.show()
```

Comment: perhaps `sns.countplot([str(a) for a in df.dtypes])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to pass the `dtypes` series, but make sure to convert the type objects to string. Matplotlib has trouble displaying labels that you passed as `numpy.dtype`s. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[12, 4, 5, None, 1],  
                   "B":[7, 2, 54, 3, None],  
                   "C":[20, 16, 11, 3, 8],  
                   "D":[14, 3, None, 2, 6]})  

sns.countplot(df.dtypes.map(str))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]